# Should the ssh fingerprint change when the sshd port changes

Tags: ssh, openssh

After changing the sshd port in OpenSSH 8.2, I found that the ssh fingerprint changed.  This surprised me since I had assumed it was just dependent on the public key.

What does the fingerprint depend on?  Is the port part of it?

On closer examination it looks like the key changed from ssh-rsa to ecdsa-sha2-nistp256.  It looks like the server has multiple key files.  What determines which key is used and what might have caused a change?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the official documentation, but ran into a similar confusion so just experimented a bit.

The hostnames in fingerprints (in `.ssh/known_hosts`) are hashed, but you can check them with `ssh-keygen -H -F 'remote'` (you'd see `Host remote found...`)

It seems that if you're using the default port (22), when you run `ssh remote` the first time, the fingerprint will only contain the hostname.
You can check this with `ssh-keygen -H -F 'remote'` (you'd see `Host remote found...`)

Now, if you change the sshd port on `remote` (say, to `1234`), seems that ssh is still happy with it, because it tries matching against the hostname without the port.
You can see that with the `-v` flag:

```
$ ssh -v remote -p 1234
debug1: Authenticating to remote:1234 as 'user'
...
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host 'remote' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:11
```

However -- if the first time you ssh onto `remote` is with a custom port (`ssh remote -p 1234`), then it seems to remember the hostname with port:

- `ssh-keygen -H -F 'remote'` -- doesn't result in anything
- `ssh-keygen -H -F '[remote]:1234'` -- results in a match

The ssh output changes slightly too, it's checking both host and port now:

```
$ ssh -v remote -p 1234
...
debug1: Host '[remote]:1234' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:12
...
```

Now if you change the remote sshd port to something else, say back to `22`, and run `ssh remote`, ssh won't be able to verify the host, because it only knows about `[remote]:1234`, not `remote`.
(I guess in theory it could still check all 65535 ports against `.ssh/known_hosts` and give a friendlier error message).

Regarding the key choice: same `-v` flag might be helpful here:

```
...
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<redacted>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <redacted> agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <redacted> agent
...
```