# Why does ssh fingerprint change?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I host a gitlab in docker on my home lab.

```
gitlab:
    image: "gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest"
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = "gitlab-ssh.xxx"
    ports:
      - "40080:80"
      - "40022:22"
```

I found that the ssh fingerprint is incorrect.
When I connect to gitlab using ssh, the ssh fingerprint displayed is

```
ssh git@gitlab-ssh.xxx
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:kKIZJDhaUVz/i7EzD7U/eXSoMbpNjd0oe2+HTFpfyBY
```

But the ssh fingerprint shown on the gitlab page is

```
SHA256:eN+NZysTvGg1Z5kXaCXwpkINMD7Bv4tpWuMuhoNdhR4
```

On gitlab docker container, same as the gitlab page.

```
SHA256:eN+NZysTvGg1Z5kXaCXwpkINMD7Bv4tpWuMuhoNdhR4
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838859/should-the-ssh-fingerprint-change-when-the-sshd-port-changes) is a similar question, but there is no great answer.